# How do I get a UMD build of React DnD?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I merely want to reference React DnD from a webpage using `<script>` tags -
 none of this server side business.

Is there a minified version I can download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dnd@2.5.4/dist/ReactDnD.min.js"></script>
```

The above link should be the latest version.

Comment: Epic, thanks. How would one go about finding that link?

Comment: @IanWarburton from the latest articles I have been reading on medium it seems unpkg.com has become the defacto standard for providing UMD build of NPM modules such as React an friends.  That being said, I just did a search for `unpkg React DnD` in a search engine.  I hope this comment helps.